# How to trigger a "BottomSheet" to expand when clicked on a view which is on a different fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, bottom-sheet

I am working on a NavigationDrawer Activity.I also have a tabbed fragment which is opened by a navigation. I have a RecyclerView in one of the tabs.I have set the views of the RecyclerView to listen to clicks.

In the MainActivity of the NavigationDrawer I populate the BottomSheet so that it is visible throughout the navigations.  And I have a textView in the Bottomsheet.

Now I want to change the contents of the textView(in the Bottomsheet) the title/description of the of the view clicked from the RecyclerView(or ViewHolder).
[image: Bottomsheet having the textview]

[image: RecyclerView]
Populating my BottomSheet at MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    nameholder=findViewById(R.id.nameolder);
ConstraintLayout llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(250);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState{}
        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

I made the viewHolder able to listen clicks.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView name;
    public TextView description;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        ListItem item=mListItems.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"this is",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",item.getName());
        intent.putExtra("description",item.getDescription());
        mActivity.nameholder.setText(item.getName());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is my Tabbed Fragment.

```
public class FragmentTabLayoutLibrary extends Fragment {
public FragmentTabLayoutLibrary() {}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);
    ViewPager vp_pages=view.findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new FragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    vp_pages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tbl_pages= view.findViewById(R.id.tbl_pages);
    tbl_pages.setupWithViewPager(vp_pages);
    return view;
}
class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new SongsListRecyclerview();
            case 1:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:return "Recycler";
            case 1:return "Home";
            default:return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

My RecyclerView is in the Recycler tab.

Please help anyone.I don't need code.I just want a way to trigger the Bottomsheet from the RecyclerView.Since the RecyclerView is not in the same main activity I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you have a Fragment displaying RecyclerView items.And this fragment is hosted in the MainActivity which is controlling the BottomSheet.

1- You have to create an Interface to achieve the communication from `SongsListRecyclerview` to `MainActivity` as in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity)

let us say that the interface that you created look like:

```
 interface OnSongSelectedListener{
    void onSongSelected(String title, String content);
 }
```

2- Once you have a reference of your listener from step 1 in your `SongsListRecyclerview` Fragment, Pass this listener to the adapter and in item click call the listener.
So your onClick will look like:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        ListItem item=mListItems.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"this is",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onSongSelectedListener.onSongSelected(item.getName(),item.getDescription());
    }
```

3- in your `MainActivity` where you implement `OnSongSelectedListener`
you will do the change

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
...
  @Override
   public void onSongSelected(String title, String content){ 
     bottomSheet.titleView.setText(title);
     bottomSheet.contentView.setText(content);
   }
}
```

Comment: got the idea.but onClick() is static so I made onSongSelected static.And finally I can't override it

Comment: do you know how the "Google Play Music" implements the same thing I am asking.Maybe they don't work with Bottomsheet

Comment: Google play Music is not open sourced. I assume it using a Foreground Service. Item click will send intent to the service and the service will update `the player` status and `Notification` status also.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493279/can-i-overlap-the-appbarlayout-with-a-persistant-bottomsheet) please check this question sir