# Can I overlap the AppBarLayout with a persistant bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, navigation-drawer

I want to overlap a AppBarLayout which contains a toolbar with a persistent bottomsheet(when it is in expanded state only).Please tell me at least a hint if it is possible.

This is my layout file where my AppBarLayout is defined

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Home"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The included layout content_main is where my bottomsheet lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.The bottomSheet will overlap the toolbar if there is no

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

The appbarlayout makes itself compulsary to be shown throughout the navigationdrawer (if the navigations are fragments).